# How to implement complex redaction?

Tags: hadoop

Hadoop can only support simple redaction via modifying HDFS configuration, for example: there is a card number A: `"1234-5678-8765-4321"`, it can be recognized by regex and then replaced by a predefined expression like: `"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"`, as shown below:

[image]

My question is can it transfer number A to: `"1234-5678-XXXX-4321"` rather than the predefined expression?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for. Mapreduce code?

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry for the unclear description...The question is about Hadoop redaction. This is the suppression of sensitive data, which is often applied on logs, hive/ impala query,hue to prevent any leaks of sensitive information.

Comment: I understand what redaction is, but you should add the relevant tags to the question to get more people to see the question. Hue offers that redaction feature, not core hadoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `( )` to grab patterns and `$1 $2 ... $n` to reuse them into the replace expression
[image]

Comment: one more question...this redaction is performed by an online test tool. But the defined redaction rules are put into the configuration file, and this .xml file may not be able to run the rules you defined.  @ozw1z5rd

Comment: I'll check this within tomorrow.