# Data pseudonymisation within HDP

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hortonworks-data-platform, bigdata

Is there any project that supports the **pseudonymisation** of the data within a Hadoop environment? (I am currently using the Hortonworks distribution).

I am aware there are multiple projects that provide with encryption and masking solutions (i.e. Dataguise, Optim and Informatica), but not so sure about pseudonymisation.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940699/how-to-implement-complex-redaction

Comment: @BinaryNerd not exactly what I was looking for but appreciate it ;)